# iOS Swift POST param and body

Tags: ios, swift, post

I'm trying to POST a key parameter and a JSON dictionary body to an API but for some reason it won't work.

Here's my work so far.
[image]

```
@IBAction func POST(_ sender: Any) {
    let url = URL(string: "http://apilink.com/updateProfile&=param")!
    let jsonObject = ["FName":"Tarik",
                      "LName":"Salama"]
    let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: [])

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "post"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.httpBody = jsonData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("error:", error)
            return
        }

        do {
            guard let data = data else { return }
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
            print("json:", json)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

I get this error when I click the POST button:
error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

What am I doing wrong?
I tried changing some stuff around after I checked some other threads like putting the parameter and the data dictionary into a key:value dictionary but the API responded and said that the data is invalid which means the whole thing was sent in an incorrect format.
Note: I'm not allowed to use 3rd party libraries like Alamofire and the API link is working fine as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Can you show the response of this `API` it is looks like you are not getting `JSON` response for this api

Comment: the text in the whited out squares inside your biggest red circle need to formatted as valid JSON, is it?

Comment: Nirav, I got 200 OK. What other info do you need to see?
@Mozahler Yes it's valid JSON
{ "key" : "value", "key" : "value", etc}

Comment: @Tarek the HTTP response code doesn't have anything to do with your error. Swift complains because it thinks the response is not valid JSON. Try copying the JSON **response** into a [JSON validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) to see if your problem is coming from your API or Swift code.

Comment: Ok I just checked, the error is coming from the 
`if let error = error {
                print("error:", error)
                return
            }` line. I was accidentally offline and I got the same error which means the JSON was never sent. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can check the problem by printing the response data

```
do {
            guard let data = data else { return }
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "No Conversion") //Print Here
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
            print("json:", json)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
        }
```

look at the 'Print Here' line. I believe the response is not a valid json so when you try to parse the data to JSOn it always ends up in catch block.

Comment: Ok I just checked, the error is coming from the 
`if let error = error {
                print("error:", error)
                return
            }` line. I was accidentally offline and I got the same error which means the JSON was never sent. Any ideas?

Comment: Tried your code, with API I have, It works fine. But it seems the response from your API is invalid. Please check the API. What happen when you tried it with postman. Did you get json response back?

Comment: This is really confusing. I tried another thing. You see the &=param in the URL? I removed it and I made the dictionary object as follows: [String:[String:String]] where the first String is "param" and the [String:String] is the dictionary with all my parameters like the FName, LName, etc. 
This seems to work, at least the API responds and says that the data is invalid. So I guess I'm not converting what I'm doing on Postman into Swift correctly. Can you take a look at it?

PS: Everything works fine in Postman.

Comment: Is that Url for API valid? I got the following response

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /updateProfile&amp;=param was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at apilink.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>`

I believe you are also getting the same html, which is not JSON and thus the JSONSerialization method trows error

Comment: No the one I'm using in this example isn't valid, it's like a placeholder. I can't post the real one due to NDA :S But yes everything works fine in Postman. The API is used by the Android and Web apps as well so I'm 100% sure the API isn't the issue.